# what is wrong in the program below

Tags: opengl

i am trying to compile it using command gcc -lGL -lglut ex2_6.c -o ex2_6.
Error is given below.I got this code at ihis link http://www.glprogramming.com/red/chapter02.html.See example 2-6 on this link.

```
hemkar@ubuntu:~$ gcc -lGL -lglut ex2_6.c -o ex2_6
/tmp/ccrgl3Y9.o:ex2_6.c:function reshape: error: undefined reference to 'gluOrtho2D' collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Code:

```
#include <GL/gl.h>
#include <GL/glut.h>

void display(void)
{
   GLubyte fly[] = {
      0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00,
      0x03, 0x80, 0x01, 0xC0, 0x06, 0xC0, 0x03, 0x60, 
      0x04, 0x60, 0x06, 0x20, 0x04, 0x30, 0x0C, 0x20, 
      0x04, 0x18, 0x18, 0x20, 0x04, 0x0C, 0x30, 0x20,
      0x04, 0x06, 0x60, 0x20, 0x44, 0x03, 0xC0, 0x22, 
      0x44, 0x01, 0x80, 0x22, 0x44, 0x01, 0x80, 0x22, 
      0x44, 0x01, 0x80, 0x22, 0x44, 0x01, 0x80, 0x22,
      0x44, 0x01, 0x80, 0x22, 0x44, 0x01, 0x80, 0x22, 
      0x66, 0x01, 0x80, 0x66, 0x33, 0x01, 0x80, 0xCC, 
      0x19, 0x81, 0x81, 0x98, 0x0C, 0xC1, 0x83, 0x30,
      0x07, 0xe1, 0x87, 0xe0, 0x03, 0x3f, 0xfc, 0xc0, 
      0x03, 0x31, 0x8c, 0xc0, 0x03, 0x33, 0xcc, 0xc0, 
      0x06, 0x64, 0x26, 0x60, 0x0c, 0xcc, 0x33, 0x30,
      0x18, 0xcc, 0x33, 0x18, 0x10, 0xc4, 0x23, 0x08, 
      0x10, 0x63, 0xC6, 0x08, 0x10, 0x30, 0x0c, 0x08, 
      0x10, 0x18, 0x18, 0x08, 0x10, 0x00, 0x00, 0x08};
   GLubyte halftone[] = {
      0xAA, 0xAA, 0xAA, 0xAA, 0x55, 0x55, 0x55, 0x55, 
      0xAA, 0xAA, 0xAA, 0xAA, 0x55, 0x55, 0x55, 0x55, 
      0xAA, 0xAA, 0xAA, 0xAA, 0x55, 0x55, 0x55, 0x55,
      0xAA, 0xAA, 0xAA, 0xAA, 0x55, 0x55, 0x55, 0x55, 
      0xAA, 0xAA, 0xAA, 0xAA, 0x55, 0x55, 0x55, 0x55, 
      0xAA, 0xAA, 0xAA, 0xAA, 0x55, 0x55, 0x55, 0x55,
      0xAA, 0xAA, 0xAA, 0xAA, 0x55, 0x55, 0x55, 0x55, 
      0xAA, 0xAA, 0xAA, 0xAA, 0x55, 0x55, 0x55, 0x55, 
      0xAA, 0xAA, 0xAA, 0xAA, 0x55, 0x55, 0x55, 0x55,
      0xAA, 0xAA, 0xAA, 0xAA, 0x55, 0x55, 0x55, 0x55, 
      0xAA, 0xAA, 0xAA, 0xAA, 0x55, 0x55, 0x55, 0x55, 
      0xAA, 0xAA, 0xAA, 0xAA, 0x55, 0x55, 0x55, 0x55,
      0xAA, 0xAA, 0xAA, 0xAA, 0x55, 0x55, 0x55, 0x55, 
      0xAA, 0xAA, 0xAA, 0xAA, 0x55, 0x55, 0x55, 0x55, 
      0xAA, 0xAA, 0xAA, 0xAA, 0x55, 0x55, 0x55, 0x55,
      0xAA, 0xAA, 0xAA, 0xAA, 0x55, 0x55, 0x55, 0x55};

   glClear (GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
   glColor3f (1.0, 1.0, 1.0);

/*  draw one solid, unstippled rectangle,       */      
/*  then two stippled rectangles                */
   glRectf (25.0, 25.0, 125.0, 125.0);
   glEnable (GL_POLYGON_STIPPLE);
   glPolygonStipple (fly);
   glRectf (125.0, 25.0, 225.0, 125.0);
   glPolygonStipple (halftone);
   glRectf (225.0, 25.0, 325.0, 125.0);
   glDisable (GL_POLYGON_STIPPLE);

   glFlush ();
}

void init (void) 
{
   glClearColor (0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0);
   glShadeModel (GL_FLAT);    
}

void reshape (int w, int h)
{
   glViewport (0, 0, (GLsizei) w, (GLsizei) h);
   glMatrixMode (GL_PROJECTION);
   glLoadIdentity ();
   gluOrtho2D (0.0, (GLdouble) w, 0.0, (GLdouble) h);
}

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
   glutInit(&argc, argv);
   glutInitDisplayMode (GLUT_SINGLE | GLUT_RGB);
   glutInitWindowSize (350, 150);
   glutCreateWindow (argv[0]);
   init ();
   glutDisplayFunc(display);
   glutReshapeFunc(reshape);
   glutMainLoop();
   return 0;  
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to use `gluOrtho2D()` without linking against the [OpenGL Utility Library](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenGL_Utility_Library).

Try this:

```
gcc ex2_6.c -o ex2_6 -lGL -lglut -lGLU
```

Or switch to `glOrtho()` and sidestep the whole issue.

Answer (score 1):

Library linker flags need to go to the end:

```
cc -o foo foo.c -lGL -lglut
```

Comment: @hemkar Then you have additional errors. Are you sure you are indeed doing this?

Comment: Not the downvoter, however I'd assume it's because this does not address the error that relates to gluOrtho2D. It's a GLU entrypoint, not a GL or glut one.

Comment: can anybody tell me how reshape() function works in general and how it is working in this particular program as well.how it is getting its parameter? it is being called with glutReshapeFunc(reshape) without passing any parameter!